# Java - initializing a string to null explicitly

Tags: java

Java strings are initialized to null if you don't set them to a value:

```
String str;
```

The value of the above string is null.

I see in code online people doing the following:

```
String str = null;
```

But isn't that redundant since it is set to null anyway? What is the best practice for initializing a string?

Comment: I always set it to null myself. It's a habit, but also helps that I do this everywhere and don't get `variable not initialized` errors.

Comment: The first options are better. All variables objects by default is null so the second is redundant

Comment: @Onregs not all variables are set to null by default. Refer to the duplicate question's answer.

Comment: Local variables must be initialised to null, they will not be initialised automatically. No, it is not always redundant. You shouldn't initialise field variables though, they will be initialised automatically.

Comment: @tima can you give me example pls? I think you mean primitives but objects are always null

Comment: @tima definite assignment analysis is there to help you make sure that you've assigned the value you need to assign before you use it - unless you actually need to assign null, you may end up forgetting to reassign the correct value in some logical branch, and then you end up with a NPE. You're just disregarding free help from the compiler.

Comment: @AndyTurner like I said, it's a habit, I can't change now :)